# Mailcore retrieving folders and compose functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2, mailcore

I am using Mailcore (https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2) for accessing IMAP mail.

I could able to get all the inbox mails using this sample given. I able to retrieve all the mail folders as well. I want to implement compose functionality using this. I am not getting API details or samples for this. Could someone please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

IMAP is an email retrieval protocol, it is not used for sending. For that, you have SMTP. So you were probably just looking in the wrong place...

I've never used mailcore2, but after reviewing their wiki pages, I found their example for composing and sending messages using STMP [here](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/wiki/SMTP-Examples).